# JSF: Conversion Error setting value '<some string>' for 'null Converter'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am getting the null Converter error for what I thought was a very simple scenario:

```
<!-- My View -->
<ui:composition template="/template/template_v1.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<!-- Simplified for clarity -->    
<h:form>
    <div class="block-panel customer-data">
        <h:outputLabel for="txtUsername">Username:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="txtUsername" name="Username" 
                     value="#{userBean.user.id}"
                     styleClass="text" />
        <rich:message id="errorUsername" for="txtUsername"/>
    </div>
    <!--  Other fields omitted for clarity  -->
</h:form>
```

```
/* The User Bean - simplified */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        // Contains logic for reading a user from the database or creating a new
        // user object
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

### }

```
/* The user Entity - Simplified */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class User implements IEntity<String>, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", length = 50)
    @NotNull(message = "{userIdMandatory}")
    @Size(max = 50)
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

### }

```
/* The IEntity interface */
public interface IEntity<ID extends Serializable> {
    ID getId();
    void setId(final ID pId);
}
```

So essentially I'm trying to bind a string property of my user entity to a inputText field. As far as I'm concerned there should be no need for a conversion so I shouldn't be getting the error I'm seeing.

Interestingly, if I add the following getter and setter to my entity:

```
public String getTmpId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setTmpId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

And then make the necessary changes to my view to bind to tmpId rather than id, everything works as expected.

This seems like a bug to me either to do with the fact that I am binding to a getter/setter defined in an interface, defined in a generic interface or because the getter is marked with the Id attribute. I would appreciate someone else's ideas however.

As an aside, I have inherited this design and don't particularly like it so I may just end up refactoring it to introduce a new username property rather than trying to use the Id.

Comment: What exactly do you get as `'<some string>'`? Of which object exactly is that the `toString()` representation?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear... I get what ever string I enter into the text box in place of <some string>

Comment: Oh okay, just the literally entered string? Well, that's strange then.  Are you sure that `#{userBean.user}` is not null, nor has incompatibly changed suring the submit? To start, doing DB interaction job in a getter like `getUser()` does not look right.

Comment: Yes you're probably right, it's probably not the cleanest design, but I've inherited this code and would like to understand why it's not working before making changes. Despite the possibly dubious design, I don't think it's anything to do with getUser() as if I bind to a different property on the user entity (see original question) it works as expected.

Comment: And yes it's the literally entered string that appears in the error message.

Comment: Hmm ok. I'd suggest to put a breakpoint on `UIInput#getConvertedValue()` and then track all the way until you end up in a HTML basic input renderer and then check in there what class `ValueExpression#getType()` exactly returned.

Comment: ValueExpression#getType() returns serializable rather than string which is why I am getting the error. Debugging further it seems to be a problem with BeanELResolver but I've been unable to find the right version of the source code to be able to debug any deeper. It seems like a very obscure problem somewhere as simply adding the TmpId getter/setter resolves the problem - even when leaving the view bound to the id property (userBean.user.id). I've spent enough time on this for what is an odd design anyway, so I'm going to refactor the user entity instead of continuing down this 'rabbit hole'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge I believe this is caused by an obscure bug in BeanELResolver which is used to get the type of the property being bound to - rather than returning String it is returning Serializable, for which there is no converter and hence the error I am seeing.

It's not particularly elegant, but I have worked around this by adding a userId property to my userBean and then binding to that in my view instead of the Id property on the user entity. I then use that value to set the Id manually on the entity when I save it:

```
<!-- My New View -->
<ui:composition template="/template/template_v1.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<!-- Simplified for clarity -->    
<h:form>
    <div class="block-panel customer-data">
        <h:outputLabel for="txtUsername">Username:</h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="txtUsername" name="Username" 
                     value="#{userBean.userId}"
                     styleClass="text" />
        <rich:message id="errorUsername" for="txtUsername"/>
    </div>
    <!--  Other fields omitted for clarity  -->
```

```
/* The New User Bean - simplified */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private string userId;
    private User user;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        // Contains logic for reading a user from the database or creating a new
        // user object
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void saveUser() {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            user.setId(userId);
        }
        // Actual saving omitted for brevity
    }
}
```